# where is the defination of function open which is declared in fcntl.h?

Tags: c++, file

When I want to open a file without buffer, I will include the header file `fcntl.h` and write a program just like this:

```cpp
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){
    int fd = open("path/to/onefile",O_RDONLY);
    //some statements not important
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

But,it is confusing who implement the function `open`.
Just as I can guess, the definition of the function `open` looks like this:

```
MOV rax, OPEN_NUM;  // OPEN_NUM is a number of syscall 
...                 // some instructions which set other related register
syscall             // trigger syscall entry point
...                 //  return from syscall
```

However, where I can find the defination of function `open`?

Comment: It is part of the system's libc, e.g. on most linux systems glibc, like all the standard C functions as well.

Comment: Are you just looking for the man page? https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html